# qt restapi post no response

Tags: qt, post, response, rest

I transfer data with "qt" over rest api on an nestJs service. the nestJs service work fine, but I don't receive any response in "qt".

here a snippet from qt:

```
QNetworkRequest request;
request.setUrl(myUrl);
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/json");

QNetworkAccessManager *restClient;
restClient = new QNetworkAccessManager();
QNetworkReply *replay = restClient->post(request, *payload);
QByteArray result = replay->readAll();
qDebug() << result;
```

the console print is always:

```
""
```

the correct response from my nestJs service is (received with insomnia rest client tool):

```
{
  "Generated": {},
  "ErrorCode": 200,
  "ErrorText": "OK"
}
```

thanks for help.

Comment: You must wait for request to finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requests are asynchronous so you must use the finished signal:

```
QNetworkReply *replay = restClient->post(request, *payload);
QObject::connect(replay, &QNetworkReply::finished, [replay](){
    QByteArray result = replay->readAll();
    qDebug() << result;
    replay->deleteLater();
});
```